# How to correct capitalize words containing ä,ö,ü?

Tags: javascript, multiline, acrobat

I have a multiline textfield in which the user can enter e.g. "märz märz".
Now I want to change both words into "März März".

I tried this code (in custom keystroke script):

```
var z=event.value.replace(/[\w\u00c0-\u00d6\u00d8-\u00f6\u00f8-\u00ff]+/igm, function(m){ return m.toLowerCase();});
var x=z.toLowerCase();
var y = x.replace(/\b./igm, function(m){ return m.toUpperCase();});
event.value = y;
```

the result is: "MäRz MäRz"

How does the script have to be edited so the result is: "März März"?

Comment: What constitutes are word for you? Anything that can be told apart by whitespace?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, thats right. But it think i have to edit my question, because my textfield is multiline.

Comment: So why don't you simply match `/(^|\s+)\S/g` and `.toUpperCase()` that?

Comment: @Bergi that works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go no need for a regex if its always the first letter:

```
var start =  "märz märz";

var text = start.split(' ').map(function(el) {
  return el.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + el.slice(1);
}).join(' ');


console.log(text); // "März März"
```

JSBin:

https://jsbin.com/sohamo/edit?js,console

Comment: There's a need for regex if it's not always only spaces :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```js
var a = "märz märz, april mai oktober\nnovember februar\naugust";

function capitalize(string) {
  var b = string.split(" ");
  b.forEach(function(e, i, a) {
    a[i] = e[0].toUpperCase() + e.slice(1);
    if (a[i].indexOf("\n") > 0) {
      a[i] = e[a[i].indexOf("\n") + 1].toUpperCase() + a[i].slice(a[i].indexOf("\n") + 2);
    }
  });
  return b.join(" ");
}

document.write(capitalize(a));
```

Comment: hi, nearly correct, because the first word of the new line did not changed and stays lowercase. It would be great if this can resolved.

Comment: Ok, i have updated the function. New lines are also recognized now.

Answer (score 0):

based on bergi's hint, the code has to be edited to this:

```
event.value = event.value.replace(/(^|\s+)\S/g, function(m){ return m.toUpperCase();});
```

That code exactly does what i want.

Every word in every line is Capitalized.

Thanks.

Comment: even more compact with arrow function:
`event.value = event.value.replace(/(^|\s+)\S/g, m => m.toUpperCase())`